# error after adding activiti:eventListener in my file.bpmn

Tags: java, spring, activiti

I'm trying to add a listener in my file.bpmn to detect if I've arrived to the endEvent :

```
<process id="workflow" name="workflow" isExecutable="true">
    <extensionElements>

 <activiti:eventListener class="ActivitiProcessEndListener" />
    </extensionElements>
    <startEvent id="startEvent1"></startEvent>
```

my ActivitiProcessEndListener implements ActivitiEventListener
after executing my circuit i have the following error:

```
o.a.e.d.event.impl.ActivitiEventSupport  : Exception while executing event-listener, which was ignored

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.getValue(MetaObject.java:113)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicContext$ContextMap.get(DynamicContext.java:94)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicContext$ContextAccessor.getProperty(DynamicContext.java:108)
    at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2434)
    at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:114)
    at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.OgnlCache.getValue(OgnlCache.java:44)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ExpressionEvaluator.evaluateIterable(ExpressionEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ForEachSqlNode.apply(ForEachSqlNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:33)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicSqlSource.getBoundSql(DynamicSqlSource.java:41)
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.getBoundSql(MappedStatement.java:280)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:80)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:120)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:113)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.selectListWithRawParameter(DbSqlSession.java:440)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.selectList(DbSqlSession.java:431)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntityManager.findProcessInstanceByQueryCriteria(ExecutionEntityManager.java:140)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessInstanceQueryImpl.executeList(ProcessInstanceQueryImpl.java:597)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.AbstractQuery.executeSingleResult(AbstractQuery.java:183)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:166)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.AbstractQuery.singleResult(AbstractQuery.java:129)
    at ActivitiProcessEndListener.onEvent(ActivitiProcessEndListener.java:62)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.DelegateActivitiEventListener.onEvent(DelegateActivitiEventListener.java:45)
```

this is my listener :

```
public class ActivitiProcessEndListener implements ActivitiEventListener {
@Override


public void onEvent(final ActivitiEvent event) {

     if (event.getType() == ActivitiEventType.PROCESS_COMPLETED || event.getType() == ActivitiEventType.PROCESS_CANCELLED
                || event.getType() == ActivitiEventType.PROCESS_COMPLETED_WITH_ERROR_END_EVENT) {
            ActivitiEntityEvent aee = (ActivitiEntityEvent) event;
            LOGGER.info(String.format("Instance evt, type [%s], id=[%s], processDefinitionId=[%s]", event.getType(), event.getProcessInstanceId(), event.getProcessDefinitionId()));
            if (event.getProcessInstanceId() != null) {
                ProcessInstance procInst = event.getEngineServices().getRuntimeService().createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(event.getProcessInstanceId()).singleResult();
                Task task = event.getEngineServices().getTaskService().createTaskQuery().executionId(event.getExecutionId()).singleResult();
                if (task == null) {
                    task = event.getEngineServices().getTaskService().createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(event.getProcessInstanceId()).singleResult();
                }
                if (task == null) {
                    LOGGER.debug("No task ");
                }
                WfTaskInstance tskInst = new WfTaskInstance(task, aee);
                tskInst.setBusinessKey(procInst.getBusinessKey());
                Map<String, Object> variables = event.getEngineServices().getRuntimeService().getVariables(event.getExecutionId());
                String codeCircuit = event.getProcessDefinitionId().substring(0, event.getProcessDefinitionId().indexOf(":"));
                WfBusinessMethodsRegistry.getInstance().callBusinessMethod(codeCircuit, tskInst, variables);
            }

            return;
        }

            if (event.getProcessInstanceId() != null) {
                ProcessInstance procInst = event.getEngineServices().getRuntimeService().createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(event.getProcessInstanceId()).singleResult();

                if (procInst != null && procInst.getActivityId() != null && "EndEvent".equalsIgnoreCase(procInst.getActivityId())) {
                    Long sId = (Long) event.getEngineServices().getRuntimeService().getVariable(event.getExecutionId(), "id");

                    final String queryStr = "UPDATE table SET  DATE = :date WHERE id = :id";

                    final EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerFactoryRegistry.INSTANCE.getNamedEntityManagerFactory("Persistence").createEntityManager();
                    final Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
                    query.setParameter("date", LocalDate.now());
                    query.setParameter("id", sId);
                    query.executeUpdate();

                }
            }
        }



        }
```

the problem is in this line :

```
ProcessInstance procInst = event.getEngineServices().getRuntimeService().createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(event.getProcessInstanceId()).singleResult();
```

i have modified my listener like this but i have an error in  `query.executeUpdate()`

```
@Override
public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        Long sId= (Long) execution.getVariable("Id");

        final String queryStr = "UPDATE table SET  DATE = :date WHERE id = :id";

        final EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerFactoryRegistry.INSTANCE.getNamedEntityManagerFactory("Persistence").createEntityManager();
        final Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
                query.setParameter("date", LocalDate.now());
                query.setParameter("id", sId);
                query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Exception:

```
2018-02-20 14:22:58.340 ERROR 424 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.e.impl.interceptor.CommandContext    : Error while closing command context


javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:54)
at wf.activiti.tools.ActivitiProcessEndListener.notify(ActivitiProcessEndListener.java:99)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.ExecutionListenerInvocation.invoke(ExecutionListenerInvocation.java:34)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DelegateInvocation.proceed(DelegateInvocation.java:37)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocation(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:25)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.notify(ClassDelegate.java:99)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:42)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:650)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:643)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationActivityEnd.java:78)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:650)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:643)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:650)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:643)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.end(ExecutionEntity.java:406)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.NoneEndEventActivityBehavior.execute(NoneEndEventActivityBehavior.java:24)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:60)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:650)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:643)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:52)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
```

Comment: upload your listener implementation please, your case is ambiguous

Comment: i have edited the post (thank you for answering)

Answer (score 0):

The [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror) error comes when the program runs indefinitely.

In your case, you implemented the event listener but did not specified as to which event it should listen. the class [ActivitiEvent](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/delegate/event/ActivitiEvent.html) has a lot of implementations therefore executing your code every time any event is triggered, hence causing a stackoverflow error.

You should execute your logic when

`<activiti:executionListener event="end" class="{your.class}"></activiti:executionListener>`

Follow this example in [userguide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#eventDispatcher) to implement your listener appropriately.

Comment: i have added the events (see above) but still have the same error

Comment: I have tried this one too (yesterday) <activiti:executionListener event="end" class="ActivitiProcessEndListener"></activiti:executionListener>  but it didn't work

Comment: should i use both of them : activiti:executionListener  and activiti:eventListener  ?

Comment: for `activiti:executionListener` to work your class should implement `org.activiti.engine.delegate.ExecutionListener`, override its `notify(..)`

Comment: don't use `eventListener` probably some issue exists in the API.

Comment: but with ExecutionListener i cant use this methode "public void onEvent(final ActivitiEvent event)"

Comment: you don't have to use it, execution listener will be automatically triggered when event described in the xml `event="end"` occurs

Comment: i have modified my listener but now i have an other error while executing my query ,i don't know if it is linked to the fact that i'm using notify (because it worked before)

Comment: @L.E are you executing your query on Activiti's table?